# What to Show some data On my view but there is a Error In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Here I am trying to add, Add Comment feature and it's causing a problem to show data.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $chatterreply =  new Chatterreply;
    $chatterreply->reply = $request->body;
    $chatterreply->chatter_post_id = $request->chatter_post_id;
    $chatterreply->chatter_discussion_id = $request->chatter_discussion_id;
    $chatterreply->save();
    $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$request->chatter_post_id)->get();
     $chatter_editor = config('chatter.editor');

    if ($chatter_editor == 'simplemde') {
        // Dynamically register markdown service provider
        \App::register('GrahamCampbell\Markdown\MarkdownServiceProvider');
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($chatterreplies); die;
    return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies','chatter_editor'))->with('chatter_alert','Add Comment Successfully');

}
```

And Here Is Where I am passing the variable

```
 $chatter = session()->pull('chatter');
            return view('chatter::discussion', compact('discussion', 'posts', 'chatter_editor'))->with('chatterreplies',$chatter);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What's the error? What version of Laravel are you using? You've over-tagged this question. Also your `store` should redirect after creating the new data, not return a view.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke the data is now showing but when I test the data by using dd(''); it shows data on that view, I am using laravel 5.6.  The return was suggested by one of the stackoverflow member.

Comment: `view("chatter::discussion")` doesn't seem right; you use dot-notation (`"folder.file"`) to specify the `.blade.php` file you want to show with the `view()` method. Also, `view(..., compact(...))` and `view(...)->with(...)` accomplish the same thing; use one or the other.

Comment: But sir I am doing it in a package so for that :: is used  as chatter is name of package and discussion is the view @TimLewis

Comment: Hmm... I've never seen `::` used in that context, so I can't say if it's right or wrong; just an observation.

Comment: ok sir @TimLewis

Comment: It's still not clear what the issue is sorry.

Comment: @TimLewis It works, it's a namespace or "package hint" for vendor provided views that are found outside of your resource/views folder.

Comment: If anyone may please help me through TeamViewer

Comment: @RossWilson Sir the issue is I am storing comments and when I pass data to show those comments on view they are not working(Visible) but when I use dd("") to test  then it shows me the required data.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using the controllers that come with the package?

Comment: Just to make it easy to work on, is that a wrong practice @RossWilson

Comment: Ok. Well after having a quick look at the package it's because the blade file that comes with it expects certain variables to be present i.e. `$discussion`, `$posts` and `$chatter_editor`. There is nothing in the blade file for `$chatterreplies` so that blade file won't work. I would suggest making your own blade file for this.

Comment: ok sir but my comments have to be added on the same page discussion.blade.php. So should I Include the new view in discussion page. @RossWilson